# React Native - Show loading Indicator when fetching data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I want to show a loading indicator when fetching data

so I create a loading component in root navigator, and use redux state to trigger it

```
const { isLoading } = useSelector(state => state.app)
<View>
   <Tab.Navigator>
     // ...
   </Tab.Navigator>
   {
     isLoading &&
     <View style={styles.loading}>
       <ActivityIndicator />
     </View>
   }
</View>
```

when fetching data, I need dispatch loading reducer first and turn off it when promise end

```
const appSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'app',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    SetLoadingState(state, action) {
      state.isLoading = action.payload
    }
  },
})
```

```
dispatch(SetLoadingState(true))
dispatch(AddAddress({
  ...args
}))
  .then(({ meta, payload, error }) => {
        if (payload.status === 'Success') navigation.goBack()  
  })
  .finally(() => dispatch(SetLoadingState(false)))
```

Is there any way can combine dispatch loading state and fetch data? thanks!

Comment: Is `SetLoadingState` and `AddAddress` are part of same reducer?

Comment: no... can I use dispatch in axios fetch interceptors?